# Cant get authentication filter working with embedded jetty

Tags: authentication, servlets, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

I have a REST handler servlet defined as follows (this works perfectly):

```
    //REST handler context
    ServletContextHandler restHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    restHandler.setContextPath("/");

    // Jersey REST handling servlet
    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = restHandler.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    // Tell Jersey which REST service class to load....
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", RestHandler.class.getCanonicalName());
```

I now want to add a authentication filter, which I do as:

```
    FilterHolder authFilter = restHandler.addFilter(AuthFilter.class,  "/", 
                                                    EnumSet.of( DispatcherType.ASYNC, 
                                                                DispatcherType.ERROR, 
                                                                DispatcherType.FORWARD,
                                                                DispatcherType.INCLUDE, 
                                                                DispatcherType.REQUEST));    
    if (authFilter == null) {
        dlog.debug("Failed to load authentication filter");
    };
```

All good so far, however, the filter does not fire on incoming REST. Calls still go through. The AuthFilter is straight from sample code:

public class AuthFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    private static final Logger dlog = Dlog.get();

```
public static final String AUTHENTICATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filter) 
                                                                throws IOException, ServletException {
    dlog.entry(request, response, filter);

    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authCredentials = httpServletRequest.getHeader(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER);

        AuthService authenticationService = new AuthService();
        boolean authenticationStatus = authenticationService.authenticate(authCredentials);

        if (authenticationStatus) {
            filter.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
    }
    dlog.exit();
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
}
```

}

I use handler collection as I also have a resource handler to serve static web pages besides the REST calls.

```
    HandlerCollection handlerList = new HandlerCollection();
    handlerList.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resourceHandler,  
                                            restHandler, 
                                            new DefaultHandler(), 
                                            requestLogHandler });
```

What else I need to do? I have scanned through number of related posts and come up empty. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your web.xml,please?

Comment: Not using any web.xml. All done with code up till now.

Comment: can you try to change the filter  path spec from "/" to "/*" ?

Comment: Thanks Ricard. You are brilliant. That did it :-).

Comment: One more question, the AuthFilter class that implements required stubs for init and destroy. DO I need to fill these in?

Comment: I meant stubs public void destroy() and public void init(FilterConfig arg0) for my AuthFilter class that implements javax.servlet.Filter . Thanks.

Comment: You can leave them empty but, for example you can move the instantiation of the  AuthService authenticationService to init method (if it is thread-safe).

Comment: Got it. I take it I will be required to call the init() method. I mean it is not implicitly called, right? Thanks.

Comment: And also wondering what to place in the FilterConfig argument?